# Trying to perform UISocialActivity but there is already an activity performing:<SHSheetActivityPerformer>

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, swift5, uiactivitycontroller

I am using main thread to show share options in iOS.

*[url] is my PDF data*. Every share option is working fine, except when user clicks on application which resign current application and go to third party(selected) application. For eg: If user clicks on share button, then google chrome; chrome application will open. And when user comes back to original application, user is not able to tap other options of `UIActivityViewController`. Why is this happening. On console, I am getting **below warning** (no crash):

> [ShareSheet] Trying to perform <UISocialActivity: 0x282b64a50>
> activityType:com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension
> activityTitle:UISocialActivity but there is already an activity
> performing:<SHSheetActivityPerformer: 0x283f427d0>

```
let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   self.present(ac, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I debug this issue on apple's native applications and found that this is an iOS issue. To support this statement, I've attached a video of apple's native application named as Files.

Video link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sr62440mpdpyr0s/RPReplay_Final1663641390.mp4?dl=0

Steps to reproduce this known issue of share activity controller(`UIActivityViewController`) in files application:

- Open file application
- Open a pdf file
- Click on share button
- Click on any application which results into opening other third party application such as Chrome
- Go back to file application
- Sharing options becomes unresponsive

As this issue is occurring in Files application too, thus we can say that this is an OS issue, not an issue related to my application.